# Where should I ask about how to do tech support for end users?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

There's a particular communication/education problem that I often have when helping non-savvy Windows users.  Where should I ask about how to overcome that problem?

Specifically, the problem is that Windows Explorer and Internet Explorer sound too similar, so I have a hard time getting users to open a Windows Explorer window over the phone. I'd like to ask for advice about overcoming a lack of understanding of what Explorer is and what a file browser is.

Comment: Odd mix of workplace with a requirement for specific software knowledge.  You can phrase it so that it's on topic for super user.  Maybe about opening an explorer window without specifically searching for "windows explorer".  People will ask for a reason, so preemptively describe the problem as well.  The answer will most likely involve a keyboard shortcut.  I'd suggest you ask the person if they know what the windows key is and how to use it.  If they do, win+e.  If not, inform them.  Using keyboard shortcuts is often clearer and easier to do over the phone.

Comment: A chat room? Doesn't even have to be on Stack Exchange. The web is a _huge_ place.